# KingswaySoft: Premium Look up date retrieved throwing an error

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, kingswaysoft

I'm using the Premium Lookup to match some data.
the query I'm using in the component is :

```
<fetch mapping="logical" count="1" page="1">
  <entity name="new_erpcustomer">
    <attribute name="new_lastsales" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="new_erpcustomercode" operator="eq" value="@[Column::ERPCode]" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

During the execution I got this error: "Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime Data: '05/11/2017 23:00:00' (SSIS Premium Service Lookup (Shared Assembly), v21.2.0.31501 - DtsDebugHost, v13.0.4561.14)System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException " on the column new_lastsales. I've done few attempts by changing the packaglocalID, the account's language/dateformat in CRM without any success.

Any clue on how to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by creating before the lookup a date column named 'salesDate', in the lookup instead of adding a new column with the value of the lastsales field, I assign it to salesDate and it went without any error